# How is it possible to place a input box (form) within a HTML box and position it using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have a HTML box and want to place a input text box as part of a form within and position it within the same box. Can this be done using JQuery ? If yes could someone post some code in JQuery on displaying the input box within the box. I also need to size the input box. The reason behind the use of JQuery is that I am displaying math symbols rendered by way of MathJax using JQuery. Otherwise can it be done by way of creat

```css
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
}

#container {
    width: 600px;
    height:1500px
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
}
#first {
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
 }

#second {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top:0;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
}

#third {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    right:430px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
$('#third').html('<input type="TYPE-OF-INPUT" name="INPUT-NAME" class="IF-ANY" id="IF-ANY" />')
$('#third input').css({ /*to style*/
    'prop1':'val1',
    'prop2':'val2',
    .
    .
    .
    'propn':'valn'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Geek. Could you also help with the JQuery code to render the same box #third within the main container ? If you can that would be appreciated otherwise I could ask this question in a new post.

Comment: Just do the same as for the input, only this time change the selector, like this  :
$('#container #third').css({
    'prop1':'val1',
    'prop2':'val2',
    .
    .
    .
    'propn':'valn'
});

Comment: Thanks Mr. Geek but I tried the following JQuery code to display the third box within the container and it did not display. Any suggestion on what's wrong with the code ?                                                            $('#container #third').css('<div id="third" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>')

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Geek. I got it working using the following code:                            $('#container').append('<div id="third" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>');

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar'
}).appendTo('#third');
```

```css
#third {

    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    right:430px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

input#foo {  
  border:  1px red solid; 
  /* position css*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="third">Div content</div>
```